# JavaScript передать переменную из одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript

Нужно передать переменную id из одной функции в другую. При выполнении получаю ошибку в строке return id; Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: id is not defined

```
async function getId() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
        });

        let result = await response.json();
        for (let i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
            console.log(result[i].id);
        }
        id = result[i].id
        document.getElementById('arr').textContent = (id)

        //let urlIssue = 'https://sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/2-24634?fields=summary,description';

        console.log(id);
        let objSel = document.getElementById('task')
        objSel.options[i] = new Option(id);


    } catch (err) {
        //console.error(err);
    }
    return id;
};
```

Comment: Если у вас id не глобальный, то нужно его объявить с ключевым словом let, иначе возможно случается ошибка и id не создаётся.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, объявил с let - то же самое

Comment: Потому что let должен быть выше чем try. У него блочная видимость и внизу он не доступен.

Comment: Спасибо, а как мне сделать, что бы переменная была видна за после выполнения функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать конструкцию return new Promise(). Тогда можно получить получить id или через функцию или через .then()

```js
async function getId() {
  return new Promise( async(resolve, reject) => {
     let id; //объявляем переменную id
    try {
        let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
        });

        let result = await response.json();
        for (let i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
            console.log(result[i].id);
        }
        id = result[i].id // вот теперь мы сможем редактировать id
        document.getElementById('arr').textContent = (id)
        console.log(id);
        let objSel = document.getElementById('task')
        objSel.options[i] = new Option(id);

        resolve( id );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    
  })
};


async function anotherFunc() {
  const id = await getId(); // ждем пока пройдет resolve для нашего ид

  console.log( id );
};

const id = getId()
id.then( data => {
  console.log( data ); //data = то, что будет после выполнения resolve(id)
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Теперь висит на resolve( id );

Comment: Что должно значить "висит на resolve( id )"? Это же асинхронное программирование

Comment: Не видит переменную Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: resolve is not defined
    at getId (prom.js:36)

Comment: Сорри, опечатку допустил, я когда у себя делал, не делал запросов никуда. return new Promise( async( resolve, reject )  {....};  там async дописать нужно. И не видел в коде, где было объявление переменной id, тут уже сразу изменение значения

Comment: Я уже совсем запутался)) не подскажите, что куда дописать нужно?

Comment: Я изменил основное сообщение с теми правками которые нужны. Попробуйте его скопировать

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос только на этот раз целиком. А то в этом вопросе Вы спросили почему return id выдает ошибку, Вы получили на него ответ. Сформулируйте вопрос целиком и получите на него адекватный ответ. В комментариях не особо удобно описывать код

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё заработало, только resolve нужно в цикл вставить)

Answer (score 2):

Возвращайте id внутри try{}. Id обьявлен внутри блока, так что снаружи его не существует

Comment: Сделал, как Вы сказали, После выполнения функции, переменная всё-равно не видна, мне нужно сделать так, что бы id была вмдна после выполнения функции

Comment: Что значит переменная не видна? Результатом функции будет промис с числовым значением, а не переменная. Это асинхронная функция, переменная из неё не должна быть где-то видна. Нужно использовать await или .then() - читайте про них мануалы. Например так: let id = await getId(); если это внутри асинхронной функции.